# How to fix a dropdown up and down arrow CSS issue?

Tags: html, css

In my application dropdown, arrow up and down not working properly. I have tried but I do not know how to fix this issue.
If I click the dropdown, arrow should be up.
Again if I click the dropdown, arrow should be down.

```css
.label::after {
    background-color: white;
    border-right: 3px solid black;
    border-bottom: 3px solid black;
    width: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 10px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1) rotate(45deg) translate(0px, 0px);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
    margin-top: 10px;
    content: '';
    margin-left: 5px;
} 

.label::after {
    border-right: 3px solid black;
    border-bottom: 3px solid black;
    transform: rotate(-135deg);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1) rotate(-135deg) translate(0px, 0px);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-135deg) scale(1);
    -o-transform: rotate(-135deg) scale(1);
}
```

```html
<i class="label"></i>
```

[Demo:](https://stackblitz.com/edit/multiselect-checkbox-dropdown-7umcnf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmulti-select-dropdown%2Fmulti-select-dropdown.component.css)

Comment: There is no checkbox input related to the dropdown arrow, `input[type='checkbox']:checked ~ .label::after` is never going to be applied. (And, since it's inside a button, it would be invalid to include that input anyway)

Comment: @DBS: Edited my code. Can you edit my stackblitz?!

Comment: @DBS: Edited my code. I do not know how to do it. So, Can you edit my stackblitz?

Comment: Is JavaScript solution acceptable or you want only CSS solution?

Comment: @Md.RakibulIslam: Only CSS

Comment: @Md.RakibulIslam: You have any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the state which was used to open and close the dropdown and applied it to the label and it works perfectly. I don't think only CSS is capable of handling that state.

Edit: The alignment issue is also fixed. Here is the [Stackblitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/multiselect-checkbox-dropdown-qfj6d5?file=src%2Fstyles.css,src%2Fapp%2Fmulti-select-dropdown%2Fmulti-select-dropdown.component.html).

```css
/* Changes in CSS */

button.drop-toggle .label::after {
  transform: rotate(-135deg);  
}

button.drop-toggle .label-initial::after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
}

button.drop-toggle{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!-- Changes in multi-select-dropdown-component.html -->

<i class="label" *ngIf="showDropDown"></i>
<i class="label label-initial" *ngIf="!showDropDown"></i>
```

For Checkmark color change:

```
.drop-show input[type='checkbox']{
  accent-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Md. Rakibul Islam, good solution. I was thinking about something similar at first, but I wanted to find a solution that didn't require any HTML interference and there is a CSS selector :has() which I used in my answer as well.

Comment: Arrow not aligned properly. Up and Down arrow it should be in the same place. Can you check it?

Comment: I mentioned this in my answer - the issue cause the top and left margin in Your arrow.

Comment: @EMahanK I fixed it too. It is updated in the answer and in the Stackblitz link.

Comment: Small help. Can you change checkbox background(Checkmark) color?

Comment: Yes. I updated it in the answer and in the Stackblitz link.

Comment: Sometimes not working bcoz using like this:<i class="label" *ngIf="showDropDown"></i> <i class="label label-initial" *ngIf="!showDropDown"></i>

Comment: Can you use any other method instead of  *ngIf="!showDropDown"    ?

Answer (score 1):

***Hi,***

if I correct understood Your problem is position of this arrow.

*Answer edited after the question edit.*

---

### Solution

In this case a CSS selector `:has()` can be helpful. We need to apply another styles (arrow rotation) when the dropdown is showed and you add it via JS, so we check when the dropdown container has the options.

```css
app-multi-select-dropdown:has(.drop-show) .label::after {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

I would also delete the top and left margin setting in `.label[_ngcontent-c2]::after` to avoid false rotating.

---

### Knowledge

You can read more about `:has()` selector e.g. [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has).

---

Now quickly I didn't go into the details of why, maybe it's related to the browser version, but for me this solution works on Google Chrome and on Mozilla Firefox not.

***Cheers***

Comment: You have any idea?

Comment: Hi @EMahanK, rather I won't edit your code direct. I try to help You with my answer and You can check it by yourself if that works. I came with one idea, I edited the answer. It's important to note that I struggled with a browser issue - this didn't work for me in Mozilla Firefox, but it did in Google Chrome. It may be that this problem only happened to me, but I haven't yet checked why exactly it occured. I wanted to deliver you the answer first.

Comment: Wow! You really found a good one. I also wasted a lot of time with :has() pseudo selector as well but didn't notice `.drop-show` class at that time. But it should be `app-multi-select-dropdown:has(.drop-show) .label::after` You didn't add the pseudo class `::after` Got to upvote this one (Y)